# How to find port using Get-DbaTcpPort

Tags: sql-server, powershell, dbatools

How to find whether the port used by SQL Server is static or dynamic using Get-DbaTcpPort dbatools command?

Below command doesn't show whether it's static/dynamic:

```
Get-DbaTcpPort -sqlinstance TEST
```

And below one shows too many rows:

```
 Get-DbaTcpPort -sqlinstance TEST -ALL
```

Answer (score 1):

As you already mentioned below command should work

```
 Get-DbaTcpPort -SqlInstance ComputerName\InstanceName -All
```

> -All
>
> If this switch is enabled, an object with server name, IPAddress (ipv4
>   and ipv6), port and static ($true/$false) for one or more SQL
>   Servers is returned.

[Documentation on Get-DbaTcpPort -All switch](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Get-DbaTcpPort)

This can be validated on the [github code](https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools/blob/development/functions/Get-DbaTcpPort.ps1) as well.

If you want specific port info for the connections using ipv4 then you could run:

```
$ipV4 = Test-Connection -ComputerName ComputerName -Count 1  | Select IPV4Address  
Get-DbaTcpPort -SqlInstance ComputerName\InstanceName -All |  Where-Object {( $_.IPAddress -eq $ipV4.IPV4Address )}
```

If you then want specific columns such as port number and if it is static, you could  add `select-object port, Static`

```
$ipV4 = Test-Connection -ComputerName ComputerName -Count 1  | Select IPV4Address
Get-DbaTcpPort -SqlInstance ComputerName\InstanceName -All |  Where-Object {( $_.IPAddress -eq $ipV4.IPV4Address )}  | select-object port, Static
```

---

If you want specific port info for the connections using ipv6

```
$ipV6 = Test-Connection -ComputerName ComputerName -Count 1  | Select IPV6Address
Get-DbaTcpPort -SqlInstance ComputerName\InstanceName -All |  Where-Object {( $_.IPAddress -eq $ipV6.IPV6Address )}
```

If you are on  an older version of dbatools
 then the `-detailed` flag is used instead of

```
-All
```

Comment: Thanks @Randi! I tried ipv4 version of the query you gave and found that for servers having multiple instances, it doesn't show correct output. For named instance it showed me port as 0.